# Git deployment with post-receive hook

Tags: git, bash, deployment, githooks

I want to develop my websites per git, but I have some sort of chicken and egg problem. There is one server with an git --bare repository (the main repo; /var/dev.git) one clone for the doc-root (var/www) of the apache webserver and for each user one local repository.

Ok, this works really nice, but now I want to add a "special" feature. If someone adds an .less file and pushes it to the main-repo it should be "compiled" into a css file and added to the repository. Furthermore the www-clone should pull all new files (including the new css-styles) back into the main-repo.

**My first attempt**

First I force the www-root-repo to pull the newest changes, then I try to find all less files and fire the less compiler.

```
lessc [input] [output]
```

The problem is that git seems to trigger the post-receive on a pull and a push and recalls-itself in the fashion of an infinit loop (it stops with a `error building trees`)

```
#!/bin/sh

git --git-dir /var/www/.git reset --hard HEAD
git --git-dir /var/www/.git pull /var/dev.git master

echo "###### fire LESS Compiler #####"
find /var/www -name *.less -exec sh -c 'lessc {} $(dirname {})/
    $(echo $( basename {} .less)$( echo ".css" )) >> $(dirname {})
    /less_error.log 2>&1 ' \;

echo "###### add new less-out files to repo #####"
git --git-dir /var/www/.git add .
git --git-dir /var/www/.git commit -am "css style added"
git --git-dir /var/www/.git push /var/dev.git master

echo "########### END #############"
```

To get the less error messages I pipe the stderr to the stdout (because AFAIK appending isn't possible with the stderr-pipe-redirection) and append it to an error_less-file. (second question:) How can I fore it to create the file only if an error occours? (At the moment its created on every lessc-call)

Comment: Your production webserver probably shouldn't be pushing automated changes to your Git repo. If you want things compiled in Git, do it before you push to production.

Comment: this isn't a production webserver - I use it for development. The doc-root is password-protected.

Comment: Okay, but the point still stands for a development definition of "production" - do compiles before you push to your web server's serving directory, not afterwards.

Comment: this isn't a good opinion, because everyone would have to install an lessc compiler on the local machine (inclusive node.js..)

Comment: Are other people going to be making changes to the `.less` files *without* compiling them?

Comment: everyone will edit them, but not without compiling... (the css files will be used immediatly)

Comment: Compiling before you copy to your web server's serving directory doesn't mean that you have to compile on local machines. It just means that you should have a separate step in your deployment process that handles the compiling, and that step should come before the "copy to serving directory" step. For instance, you could have a post-receive hook on your bare repo that uses `git archive` to export the files to a temporary directory, run the compiler, and then copies the result to the web server's serving directory.

Comment: ok, and what would be the best way to `catch` the new created files (error_log etc.) ?

Comment: would it be possible to add a file to a bare repository? something like git add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For clarity, let's call the /var/dev repo DEV and the /var/www repo WWW.
Make the DEV repo non-bare, so it has a worktree, and you can compile in it.
The DEV is now in /var/dev and all users must update their remote URL:

```
git remote set-url dev foo@bar:/var/dev  # Assuming SSH access
```

The DEV's post-receive hook will compile, commit and push to WWW.

```
#!/bin/sh
# Go to worktree, check out new commit
export GIT_DIR=`pwd`; cd ..; export GIT_WORK_TREE=`pwd`
git reset --hard HEAD
# fire LESS Compiler
find . -name *.less -exec sh -c 'lessc {} $(dirname {})/
    $(echo $( basename {} .less)$( echo ".css" )) >> $(dirname {})
    /less_error.log 2>&1 ' \;
# add new less-out files to repo
git add .
git commit -am "css style added"
# Push to WWW
git push /var/www master
```

The WWW post-receive hook will just check out the new commit

```
#!/bin/sh
# Go to worktree, check out new commit
export GIT_DIR=`pwd`; cd ..; export GIT_WORK_TREE=`pwd`
git reset --hard HEAD
```